# Что значит символ ? в данном случае

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Что обозначает следующая запись, а точнее занак "?" в ней?

```
 delegate void MessagesRecievedDelegate(
     VkApi owner, ReadOnlyCollection<Message> messages); 
 static event MessagesRecievedDelegate NewMessages;
 ...
 NewMessages?.Invoke(vkApi, history.Messages);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это т.н. оператор Элвиса, он же `null propagation operator`. Позволяет избегать `NullReferenceException`. Работает он так: при попытке получить значение после `?.` - он получает доступ к члену если объект до оператора не `null`, в противном случае выражение получает значение `null` - и цепочка вызовов не продолжается (в случае если там много таких операторов - `obj1?.rec1?.rec2` если `obj1` == null - дальнейшая цепочка не будет вычисляться - все выражение будет null). Оператор был введен в `C# 6`. Хорошо работает в связке с оператором `??`. Позволяя творить такие штуки:

```
var minPrice = product?.PriceBreaks?[0]?.Price ?? 0;
```

В старых версиях языка - такая конструкция была бы жутким нагромождением вложенных условных переходов с проверками.

В вашем же случае, это просто защита от того, что на событие нет подписчиков, без этого оператора в случае если подписчиков нет - приложение бы выпало с ошибкой, а с ним событие попросту не возникает.