# Вопрос по синтаксису вызова делегата в c#

Tags: c#, события

В общем, имеются в программе события, одно из них-CollectionCountChanged, которое генерируется функцией OnCollectionCountChanged:

```
public void OnCollectionCountChanged(object source, CollectionEventHandlerArgs args)
    {
        if (CollectionCountChanged != null) CollectionCountChanged(source, args);
    }
```

Visual Studio предлагает упростить вызов делегата:

```
 public void OnCollectionCountChanged(object source, CollectionEventHandlerArgs args)
    {
        CollectionCountChanged?.Invoke(source, args);
    }
```

Кто-то может объяснить, что делает эта шляпа? Ну или конкретно, что здесь делает "?". Благодарю заранее :)

Comment: Да то же самое, знак вопроса - это проверка на `null`. ([ссылка](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.26.php))

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/470646/213987 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/779606/213987

Answer (score 1):

```
CollectionCountChanged?.Invoke(source, args);
```

Такая конструкция эквивалентна следующей:

```
if(CollectionCountChanged != null)
{
    CollectionCountChanged.Invoke(source, args);
}
```

Бывает особенно удобно, когда через точку много сущностей перечислено, чтобы не проверять каждую из них на `null` по очереди:

```
LevelOne?.LevelTwo?.LevelThree?...
```

Comment: Не совсем верно. Оно эквивалентно сохранение в локальную перемену с последующей проверкой этой переменной. Это [потокобезопасный вызов делегата](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-). То, что у вас, не потокобезопасно.

Comment: Впрочем, если это какой-нибудь WPF, то есть это события UI, то это не принципиально и можно фигачить простую проверку. Все равно всё  в одном потоке.

Comment: @John Не знал таких тонкостей, спасибо )

Comment: @John Любопытно, не знал. Спасибо, что ткнули документацию.

Comment: @AK в прилинкованный к вопросу ответ закинул ссылку на док. :)